# AdMob ad disappears after soft keyboard pops-up

Tags: android, android-edittext, admob, android-softkeyboard

I am using AdMob to display ads in my Andorid app. It is a small banner at the bottom of the screen. It works fine normally. But when I click on any of the 'EditText' boxes to enter some text, a soft keyboard pops-up and it hides the ad. This is fine. But when I'm done entering the text or when I click Back to dismiss the soft keyboard or when I click on the screen-area other than the 'EditText' box the soft keyboard disappears and also the AdMob ad vanishes.

I can reload the ad but then I need to capture the event when the keyboard disappears. Besides I don't think this is the best way to resolve the problem. I would like if the ad still stays intact when the keyboard has disappeared.

Comment: Are you using v4.3.1 of the AdMob SDK? Can't seem to reproduce your issue. How are you defining your layout (specifically your TextView and your AdView)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

hello use this method in your App Manifest activity tag, this might help you.

android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden|adjustResize|adjustPan" >